# Problema ao tentar publicar múltiplos APKs na Google Play Store

Tags: ionic2, google-play

Bom dia pessoal.

Desenvolvi um aplicativo com o Ionic utilizando o plugin crosswalk.
Ao fazer a compilação, são gerados dois arquivos .apk, um para arquitetura arm7 e outro para arquitetura x86. Até aí, tudo ok. Testei ambos os apks em smartphones compatíveis e ambos funcionaram.

Executei os passos de assinatura e alinhamento descritos na [documentação do Ionic Framework](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/guide/publishing.html).

A minha dúvida ocorre ao tentar fazer a publicação na **Google Play Console**.

Existe a [seguinte documentação da Google](https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html#HowItWorks) que informa que é possível enviar mais de um apk para o mesmo aplicativo. Nesta mesma documentação, diz que isto só é possível quando o **Modo Avançado** está habilitado.

*Para publicar vários APKs para o mesmo aplicativo, você deve ativar o modo Avançado na guia de arquivos APK do seu aplicativo (conforme discutido na seção anterior). Uma vez no modo avançado, você pode carregar, ativar e, em seguida, publicar vários APKs para o mesmo aplicativo.*

E no citado tópico anterior, está escrito:

*O Google Play Console oferece dois modos para gerenciar os APKs associados à sua aplicação: modo simples e modo avançado. Você pode alternar entre estes clicando no **link no canto superior direito da guia de arquivos do APK**.*

O problema é, onde está este bendito link no canto superior direito, estou procurando a horas e não o encontro.

Obrigado pela atenção.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver depois de muita luta.

O que eu fiz foi:

1 - Executei uma compilação, que gerou os APKs com a versão interna 100012, assinei, alinhei, fiz o upload da versão arm7 e desprezei o x86 gerado nesta mesma compilação.

2 - Executei uma nova compilação, que gerou as APKs com a versão interna 100014, assinei, alinhei e fiz o upload da versão x86 e desprezei o arm7 gerado nesta mesma compilação.

Ao enviar os dois apks para a Google Play Store, eles foram aceitos.

Aos que tiverem o mesmo problema, ao pesquisar na documentação da Google, verão que lá eles mencionam uma opção chamada Modo Avançado. Esta opção não existe mais, agora, por padrão, são aceitos mais de um APK para a mesma versão do APP.

Comment: Bom achado. Parece que ao enviar o segundo APK em uma arquitetura separada você agora tem uma opção para *reter* o APK anterior correto? ([fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43540557/664577))